# Adding Drag & Drop functionality to elements

Tags: android-studio, drag-and-drop

I want to make some elements of my app able to be dragged and dropped by the user, so that the user can customize the position and design his own UI.

What I mean by drag and drop is that for example, when you hold and drag the icons or widgets on your phone, you can customize their position. So I want to make some text or images of my app function just like that.

Thanks for the help!